# What is the difference between android.opengl and javax.microedition.khronos.opengles packages?

Tags: android, opengl-es, java-me, package

Just couldn't find anything regarding the purpose of `android.opengl` classes anywhere on the web: they seem to be copies of `javax.microedition.khronos.opengles` - just with static vs member methods.

So is there any special meaning in using them instead of J2ME classes: are they supposed to be faster, have additional functionality, simpler to work with?

I think of using them instead of passing that GL reference all the time.

Comment: I know it may create problems when porting but that does not seem to be a big issue for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, just in case someone is really interested in the difference between android.opengl and OpenGL ES standard javax.microedition.khronos.opengles packages, the following can be found in Android's classic ApiDemos project: javadoc for com.example.android.apis.graphics.StaticTriangleRenderer class tells that android.opengl package simply provides a bit more functionality then standard khronos package, and, quite handy, it's easier for C developers who can simply write glBindBuffer(...) instead of ((GL20) gl).glBindBuffer(...).

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is that the Android ones are optimized and adapted for Android. It's the same with the SAX parser there is the `org.xml.sax` package and the `android.sax` package but I think both versions of the parser are optimized for Android.

Comment: The thing is traceview tool in SDK shows static call "GLES10.glClear" to be much slower than virtual "gl.glClear". In other words, Android-specific classes appear to be slower than j2me generic ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Android includes support for high
>   performance 3D graphics via the OpenGL
>   API — specifically, the OpenGL ES API.
>
> OpenGL ES is a flavor of the OpenGL
>   specification intended for embedded
>   devices. Versions of OpenGL ES are
>   loosely peered to versions of the
>   primary OpenGL standard. Android
>   currently supports OpenGL ES 1.0,
>   which corresponds to OpenGL 1.3. So,
>   if the application you have in mind is
>   possible with OpenGL 1.3 on a desktop
>   system, it should be possible on
>   Android.